# What exactly does epsilon represent in master theorem?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, master-theorem

I understand substitution method and recursion trees. I understand how to use master theorem but don't understand it's proof or intuitive explanation, specifically i don't understand where does the epsilon value come from in the theorem

The Master's Theorem states:

[image]

I am studying from CLRS 3rd edition, page 97. I want to know what does epsilon value represent, how do we come up with epsilon in the proof and Why do we need it. Would some other resource / book for this proof and extended master theorem proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the epsilon to state the Master Theorem. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) gives another formulation:

With `c_crit = log_b(a)`:

- if `f(n) = O(n^c)` where `c < c_crit`, then `T(n) = Θ(n^c_crit)`;
- if `f(n) = Θ(n^c_crit log(n)^k)` for any `k >= 0`, then `T(n) = Θ(n^c_crit log(n)^(k+1))`;
- if `f(n) = Ω(n^c)` where `c > c_crit`, and `a*f(n/b) <= k*f(n)` for some `k < 1` and sufficiently large `n`, then `T(n) = Θ(f(n))`.

Essentially, the epsilon in your example is to make sure that `log_b(a)-ε < log_b(a)` and `log_b(a)+ε > log_b(a)` (when `ε > 0`), just like `c < c_crit` and `c > c_crit` in this example from Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh this one is better. I would like to understand it through proof, most of the places even introduce "epsilon" suddenly. Can you provide / link a step by step proof for what you wrote? ( with why we have the k value ). I am sorry, if i sound obnoxious but i would just like to go through the proof myself once, and even CLRS introduced the epsilon suddenly ~ that threw me off

Comment: You can find the proof online. [For example](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/mm-proof.pdf).

Comment: @PratikHadawale Epsilon is a standard notation in the mathematics of limits, so CLRS probably assumed that people reading rigorous proofs about bounding behaviors would be familiar with it. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#In_functions) for details.

Comment: @pjs Ohh, that totally makes sense. Your comment solved my question. Basically, it's using the epsilon definition instead of the normal definition to make the master theorem more detailed in terms of asymptotic analysis / limits

Comment: @PratikHadawale Neither definition is more detailed than the other. Well, except for the case 2 in your example where it's missing the `log(n)^k` term. `log_b(a)-ε` where `ε > 0` is strictly equivalent to `c` where `c < log_b(a)`.

Comment: @Nelfeal Ah it's sort of starting to make sense to me, i understand both of them are the same ~ the wikipedia one suits me more. One final question, apparently the wikipedia defination is also called "extended master theorem", so will i be able to solve all the recurrences, that master theorem can, using extended master theorem ?

Comment: @PratikHadawale I assume you are talking about the extension to case 2 where `f(n) = Θ(n^c_crit log(n)^k)` and `k` is compared to `-1`. Of course this "extended" version applies to everything the "normal" version applies to, that's why it's called an extension.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, thank you your comment answered my question. I also had another question regards to k = -1. Link: [link to question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590653/understanding-case-2-of-extended-master-theorem-recurrence-relation-involv)